# How to refresh Real time NVD3.js charts with Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, charts, real-time, nvd3.js

I have a stocks application where we display real time line graph charts which refresh every second. We have live data feed coming from tcp/ip application. We bind it with Signal-R and Angular.js to display.

The Problem: 
I am able to display chart 1st time with NVD3.js, but then we are not able to bind with real-time data and refresh it every second.

I have tried with Chart.Update , redraw but no success

Can anybody provide a code-snippet where it is working for NVD3.js line chart refreshing real time data.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this repo
https://github.com/zeusjs/viz

There are some d3.js charts that are created to show data updating at certain intervals.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this function:

```
    $timeout(
function () {
                $scope.api.refresh();
            }, 1);
```